# node.js I want to query Array with promise all

Tags: node.js, promise

```
    let total = title.map(title => {
      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
         let total_count  = Village.count({
            where: {
                    m_id: title.m_id
            }
          });
          resolve(total_count);
            
      })
    });
    let date_first = title.map((title) => {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            let result = Village.count({
                where: {
                    m_id : title.m_id,
                    [Op.not]: [{date_start:null}]
                }
            });
            resolve(result)
        })
    });
    let promise = Promise.all([total,date_first]).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result)
        return result;
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    });
```

I want to query those thing. and I want to get those result or push in the Array.I don't know what should I do. Please advice me.Thank You

Comment: There seems to be no reason why you would create promises here.

Comment: Do not use promises for synchronous code.

Comment: @trincot Because I want to query 5 kind of alike thing.and I thought promise all would be fast than these thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** you shouldn't use the same parameter name for arrow functions as the collection has: `title`. Use something like `titleItem`.
**Second** you don't need to wrap by Promise already asynchronous calls `Village.count` (as I understand these are Sequelize queries).

```js
let totals = title.map(titleItem => {
  return total_count  = Village.count({
    where: {
      m_id: titleItem.m_id
    }
 });
});
 let date_firsts = title.map((titleItem) => {
  return Village.count({
           where: {
              m_id : titleItem.m_id,
              [Op.not]: [{date_start:null}]
          }
  });
});
// and you need to spread two arrays of Promises in order to await them all
let promise = Promise.all([...totals,...date_first]).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

It's better to use `await` to let your code look more sequential:

```js
let result = await Promise.all([...totals,...date_first]);
```

Comment: Thank You. Can I question? Why should I use spread? If I don't use spread,I can not see the result.I want to know the reason why. when I use spread, I cannot know which is totals and which is date_firsts.

Comment: If you wish to separate these two bunches of async operations then you need two separate `Promise.all`. You can wrap them then into a final Promise.all

Comment: Thank You Very mush!! Have a nice day.